# Is mandatory for websites to have copyright?

Tags: python, copyright-display

I'm developing my first children's website in python. I would like to know if it is mandatory for a website to have copyright?

Comment: It depends which country you are in. And we don't give legal advice on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't give legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. It isn’t.

Copyright is an inherent right. Any artwork, content or creative work which is original in nature, has inherent copyright vested in the work - which means, the copyright exists in every work which is originally created.

Filing a Copyright application, however, gives you the advantage of having an application or claim ownership, date using which you can claim your rights , etc

Comment: Not quite an "inherent right" — it is granted by Berne Convention in 1989 to its signatories. Before it, copyright had to actively be asserted (at least in the USA, I don't know about the other countries). There are also a handful of countries that have not signed the Berne Convention; I do not know what their laws say about it.

Comment: so is  there an option to get it for free in India?

Comment: @Saran i think no, we have to pay for full protection

Comment: @Amadan i said that because if we fill a copyright then that can't be separated easily so i have mentioned the word "Inherent"